# Signalr:Connect to remote host through wpf

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, signalr, signalr-hub

I have made a console application which works as a host for signal r and listens to port 8089.When I run wpf application and run that host application on localhost,every thing works fine.Now I have deployed that console application on server.Now when I try to connect ,it doesn't connect through wpf. So then I read that it supports only HTTP protocol and after reading  that I made an website which connects to the server on remote server and it is connected successfully. My question is that is there any way I can connect to that server using wpf.I want to make a desktop chat application in which all clients  will connect to same server so that it can broadcast.Any help will e appreciated

**StartUp.CS**

```
     public class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
                app.Map("/signalr", map =>
                {
                    // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                    // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                    // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                    // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                    {
                        // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                        // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                        // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                        // EnableJSONP = true
                    };
                    // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                    // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                    // path.

                    hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
                });
            }
        }


**Program.CS**


     class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
                // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
                // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
                // for more information.
                string url = "http://MyIpAddressOfServer:8089";
                using (WebApp.Start(url))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }

**MainWindowXaml.cs**

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public System.Threading.Thread Thread { get; set; }
        public string Host = "http://MyIpAddressOfServer:8089/signalr";

        public IHubProxy Proxy { get; set; }
        public HubConnection Connection { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void ActionSendButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await SendMessage();
        }

        private async Task SendMessage()
        {
            await Proxy.Invoke("Addmessage", ClientNameTextBox.Text , MessageTextBox.Text);
        }
        private async void ActionWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Active = true;
            Thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                Connection = new HubConnection(Host);
                Proxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
                Proxy.On<string, string>("addmessage", (name, message) => OnSendData(name + ": " + message ));
                Connection.Start();

                while (Active)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }) { IsBackground = true };
            Thread.Start();

        }

        private void OnSendData(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => MessagesListBox.Items.Insert(0, message)));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        private async void ActionMessageTextBoxOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                await SendMessage();
                MessageTextBox.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there are a few answers,

Here is a MS example 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

here is another example more on wpf
http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/signalr-a-complete-wpf-client-using-mvvm/

while the first link says winforms, it covers wpf as well.

In case the link goes down, you want to use this nugget package 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

The above package supports 
This package supports WinRT, Silverlight, WPF, console application, and Windows Phone clients, for both .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.

You can find more info about that nugget package at this link
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public System.Threading.Thread Thread { get; set; }
    public string Host = "http://x.x.x.x:8089/";

    public IHubProxy Proxy { get; set; }
    public HubConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void ActionHeartbeatButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await SendHeartbeat();
    }

    private async void ActionSendButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await SendMessage();
    }

    private async void ActionSendObjectButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await SendHelloObject();
    }

    private async Task SendMessage()
    {
        await Proxy.Invoke("Addmessage", ClientNameTextBox.Text, MessageTextBox.Text);
    }

    private async Task SendHeartbeat()
    {
        await Proxy.Invoke("Heartbeat");
    }

    private async Task SendHelloObject()
    {
        HelloModel hello = new HelloModel { Age = Convert.ToInt32(HelloTextBox.Text), Molly = HelloMollyTextBox.Text };
        await Proxy.Invoke("sendHelloObject", hello);
    }

    private async void ActionWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Active = true;
        Thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            Connection = new HubConnection(Host);
            Proxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

            Proxy.On<string, string>("addmessage", (name, message) => OnSendData("Recieved addMessage: " + name + ": " + message));
            Proxy.On("heartbeat", () => OnSendData("Recieved heartbeat"));
            Proxy.On<HelloModel>("sendHelloObject", hello => OnSendData("Recieved sendHelloObject " + hello.Molly + " " + hello.Age));

            Connection.Start();

            while (Active)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }) { IsBackground = true };
        Thread.Start();

    }

    private void OnSendData(string message)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => MessagesListBox.Items.Insert(0, message)));
    }

    private async void ActionMessageTextBoxOnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            await SendMessage();
            MessageTextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }

}



<Window x:Class="SignalRTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Loaded="ActionWindowLoaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                          MinWidth="149" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Message:"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Margin="5" />
    <TextBox Width="Auto"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="5,5,10,5"
             x:Name="ClientNameTextBox" />
    <TextBox Width="Auto"
             Grid.Column="2"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="5,5,10,5"
             x:Name="MessageTextBox"
             KeyDown="ActionMessageTextBoxOnKeyDown" />
    <Button Content="AddMessage"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="17,5"
            x:Name="SendButton"
            Click="ActionSendButtonClick" />

    <Label Content="Heartbeat:"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="5" />
    <Button Content="Send Heartbeat"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="17,5"
            x:Name="HeartbeatButton"
            Click="ActionHeartbeatButtonClick" />

    <Label Content="Age, Molly:"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="2"
           Margin="5" />
    <TextBox Width="Auto"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Margin="5,5,10,5"
             x:Name="HelloTextBox" />
    <TextBox Width="Auto"
             Grid.Column="2"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Margin="5,5,10,5"
             x:Name="HelloMollyTextBox"
             KeyDown="ActionMessageTextBoxOnKeyDown" />
    <Button Content="Send Object"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="17,5"
            x:Name="HelloButton"
            Click="ActionSendObjectButtonClick" />

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
             Margin="5"
             x:Name="MessagesListBox" />
</Grid>
```

```
public class HelloModel
{
    public string Molly { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I have followed the same example which is on MS ,the problem is that it works fine locally . But when I run that same console application that is working as a host on remote server my wpf application is unable to connect with it.I guess the problem is that it does not connect via tcp because my web application is still connecting to it.

Comment: So what I want to know is that if there is any way I can use signal r hosted on remote server connect to my application which is running on local desktop.

Comment: if your problem is only connecting when you deploy to a remote computer, it could be a number of things, such as firewall blocking the request on the server, or less likely on the client. It could also be dns issues on the client, that it is unable to locate the ip address of the server. you will need to make sure that from the client you are able to when typing into your browser the url that you are using for signalr on the client, that you can at least get back the error message, that is something like unknown transport or something along those lines.

Comment: technically speaking SignalR can work in your scenario, because you have tested it locally and know that your code works. You are most likely dealing with some other network related issue, such as those that I mentioned before.

Comment: Well yes it says Unknown transport .But it says the same thing when I am running it locally. Secondly I am able to connect it via website and chat is working when I run my website and use the same host.

Comment: that is a great start, is there a proxy configured in the browser that you are using to connect to the website? if so, you could perhaps have that kind of issue in the wpf client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64634/discussion-between-user2137186-and-louis-lewis).

Comment: ok I was waiting in the chat, and could not wait any longer. I did however in my waiting time, write both the wpf client and the console client. both mine are working as expected. so I would say your server side code is fine.

Comment: What was the problem in wpf client?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is or was in your wpf client, I never saw your code for it. I simply wrote it and it worked as expected, you could paste in your wpf code and I will gladly take a look for you

Comment: sorry my bad, try changing this public string Host = "http://MyIpAddressOfServer:8089/signalr"; to this public string Host = "http://MyIpAddressOfServer:8089/"; that is the first problem I see

Comment: It's still not working and what's the reason for that?

Comment: please see my updated answer with my working code, I just removed your real ip address from my code

Comment: I Did just that.Still same problem :(

Comment: Can you come to chat screen please?

Comment: Which project did you follow?

Comment: The project that you told me you followed.